# Prompting for sudo password in a setuid root binary

Tags: linux, operating-systems, sudo, binary-files, setuid

I have a setuid root binary, `with_sudo.bin`, with the following source code:

```
/* with_sudo.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    printf("\n\n ruid : %d \n euid : %d \n\n", (int)getuid(), (int)geteuid());
    system("/usr/bin/sudo cat /root/key.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

```
akshay@bluebox ~ $ ls -l with_sudo.bin
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 8684 Feb  1 22:09 with_sudo.bin
```

Even though it is a setuid root binary, sudo password is being asked.

```
akshay@bluebox ~ $ ./with_sudo.bin
ruid : 1000  euid : 0 
[sudo] password for akshay:
```

When I run the another binary without **`sudo`** in `system()`, it runs with superuser privileges.

```
/* without_sudo.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    printf("\n\n ruid : %d \n euid : %d \n\n", (int)getuid(), (int)geteuid());
    system("cat /root/key.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

```
akshay@bluebox ~ $ ls -l without_sudo.bin
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 8677 Feb  1 22:09 without_sudo.bin
```

---

> akshay@bluebox ~ $ ./without_sudo.bin
>
> ruid : 1000 
>   euid : 0
>
> :::this_is_a_secret_key:::

When the `Real UID` was made `0` along with the `Effective UID` using `setreuid(geteuid(), 0);`, the binary ran with superuser privileges without prompting for sudo password even though **`sudo`** was used.

```
/* with_sudo_ruid_elevated.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    setreuid(0, geteuid());
    printf("\n\n ruid : %d \n euid : %d \n\n", (int)getuid(), (int)geteuid());
    system("/usr/bin/sudo cat /root/key.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205070/whats-the-deal-with-all-the-different-uids-a-process-can-have) that `EUID` is used to evaluate privileges of the process to perform a particular action. Then why is **`sudo`** prompting for sudo password based on the `RUID` even when the `EUID` is `0` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s a little complicated.  The operating system *kernel* uses a process’s effective UID and GID
to determine its privileges/authorizations; they are used for

- allowing/disallowing ordinary filesystem operations (e.g., open, link/unlink)
  based on the user/group/other rules,
- setting the ownership of newly created files,
- determining what other processes a process can send signals to, and
- deciding whether a process can mount and unmount filesystems, change the date,
  shutdown the system, etc.

and probably other things. 
But, the catch is, when a ***program*** needs to make some sort of access/authorization decision,
it usually needs to use the real UID and GID. 
Consider: when your `with_sudo.c` program executes `sudo`,
the effective UID is root (0) and the real UID is you (1000), as demonstrated by your `printf`. 
*But this is exactly the same as what happens if you run `sudo` from an unprivileged shell.* 
***Whenever*** `sudo` runs,
the effective UID is 0 – so `sudo` can’t use that to decide how to behave. 
It has to use the real UID to figure out who you really,
so it can determine what you’re allowed to do in `sudo`. 
Only if the real UID is 0 does `sudo` conclude that you are “really” root,
or at least that it cannot reliably determine your real identity,
so it doesn’t know what restrictions to apply to you,
and it just executes the `cat` without asking for any further authentication from you.

Comment: Is there any **non-setuid_root** binary which prompts for authentication when invoked as `EUID 0` and non-root `RUID` ?